# Is Vectorious' Matrix.product function faster than Numpy's multiply function?

Tags: python, node.js, performance, numpy, matrix

I've been researching as to whether I should perform some data work in NodeJS or Python. I've created a couple of tests that appear to indicate that the Vectorious module used by NodeJS can perform matrix operations at a faster speed than Python's Numpy module.

Below are the two tests I composed to test element-wise multiplication between the modules. I would like to know:

- Have I designed these tests correctly? I understand that there can be a large number of intricacies involved with this type of testing.
- If these tests are designed correctly, then how come Numpy's usage is emphasised in the data space?
- Regardless of outcome, how come one outperforms the other?

I understand the second and third questions may result in very opinionated answers, I'm more focused on the first question as this drives future development.

**NodeJS Element-wise Multiplication Test:**

```
const v = require('vectorious'),
    Matrix = v.Matrix;

const size = 25000;

console.log("NodeJS: Creating matrices...")
let matrixA = Matrix.random(size, size);
console.log("NodeJS: Matrix A created.")
let matrixB = Matrix.random(size, size);
console.log("NodeJS: Matrix B created.")

console.log("NodeJS: Starting... (matrixA(0,0):" + matrixA.get(0, 0) + ")(matrixA(24999,24999):" + matrixA.get(24999, 24999) + ")")
t = process.hrtime()
matrixA.product(matrixB)
t2 = process.hrtime(t);

console.log("%s %d seconds and %d nanoseconds", "NodeJS: Duration", t2[0], t2[1]);
console.log(matrixA.get(0, 0) + " | " + matrixB.get(0, 0))
console.log(matrixA.get(24999, 24999) + " | " + matrixB.get(24999, 24999))
```

**Python Element-wise Multiplication Test:**

```
import numpy as np
import time

size = 25000

print("Python: Creating matrices...")
matrix = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (size,size))
print("Python: Created matrix A.")
matrixB = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (size,size))
print("Python: Created matrix B.")

print("Starting matrix multiplication...")

start = time.perf_counter()
matrixC = np.multiply(matrix, matrixB)
end = time.perf_counter()

elapsed = end - start
print("elapsed time = {:.12f} seconds".format(elapsed))

print("-", matrix[0])
print("-", matrixC[0])
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with NodeJS. Does `matrixA.product(matrixB)` put the result back into `matrixA`? In this case I guess it's faster because the operation is performed in-place, whereas `np.multiply` needs to allocate memory for `matrixC`. You can make the comparison fairer by preallocating `matrixC` and passing it with `out=matrixC` to the function. (Or use a not-in-place version of the multiplication in NodeJS, whichever suits your needs better.)

Comment: I updated the Numpy test to use the following two lines:
Outside the perf counter: `matrixC = np.random.uniform(0, 10, (size,size))` | Inside the perf counter: `np.multiply(matrixA, matrixB, out=matrixC)`

These changes resulted in an additional ~20 seconds being added to the time required.

Answer (score 0):

After modifying those two tests in multiple ways, including multiple sequential executions and rotating between static and prototype-driven methods for both Node.js and Python, I've determined that:

- The Node.js prototype variant is the fastest, but **only for the first iteration**. Afterwards execution averages at around 30 seconds (sample speed as Numpy with the out parameter) for element-wise multiplication between two 25,000x25,000 matrices.
- The Numpy static method is the most consistent in performance averaging at around 14 seconds for element-wise multiplication between two 25,000x25,000 matrices. I will be using Numpy for future data-driven applications.

Hopefully this assists someone else when deciding which language to invest development time for element-wise multiplication operations. I'm intrigued as to why Numpy's out parameter results in slower execution as it refers to an existing object.